# Совместимость jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

есть старый сайт, в котором кнопки которые вызывают popup с формами работают с jquery.lib.1.8.3.js и есть меню бутстрап с бургером , который отказывается работать с этой версией jquery и просит 1.9+

Что сделать с этим можно? скрины приложил
(первый с jqery bootsrap(http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js), второй c 1.8.3)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: поставить версию 1.9+ пробовал? по идеи 1.8.3 должно работать

Comment: пора забыть про старье.

Comment: Как ее поставить? Не очень понимаю, подключал пробовал так - <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-e9gNBsAcA0DBuRWbm0oZfbiCyhjLrI6bmqAl5o+ZjUA="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>, не работало

Comment: @And Пора ага, а что делать если такому старому сайту адаптив нужно сделать

Comment: Как вариант - подключить за место вашей старой - новую версию и поправить несовместимости. И странно, что все использует разные либы.